# Sphinx ignoring `toctree` options

Tags: python, python-sphinx, toctree

I am new to Sphinx and I am trying to include a `toctree` in Sphinx but it seems to be completely ignoring my `toctree` options.

I have code as shown below:

```
.. toctree::
   :titlesonly:

  foo
  bar
```

This is also ignored:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

  foo
  bar
```

With the resulting output looking something like this:

- Foo

  - Foo1

    - Foo12
  - Foo2
- Bar

  - Bar1

    - Bar12
  - Bar2

I am running `make html` to produce the HTML documents and I suppose it's possible I have a setting wrong in my conf.py file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consistent indentation is important. Move the names of the toctree entries one column to the right, and it will work.

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   foo
   bar
```

Comment: Doh!  It's always the little things